# Can I force Git to ignore my config or "site local" data when committing?

Tags: git, workflow

Right now I'm working on a project with a `config.py` file, which in the Git repo, contains lines like this:

```
debug = False
database = ''
```

But my local working copy has these lines in their place:

```
debug = True
database = 'sqlite:///site.db'
```

These lines hardly ever change, but still every time I commit I'm forced to add each change manually, so I can omit the changes to `config.py` from the index. Ideally, I'd like to find a way to tell Git to ignore changes to those lines or the entire file, but still include them in the repo, so my `git status` screen would be clean, and I could use `git commit -a`.

If that's not possible, is there a recommended workflow to avoid this mismatch between the repo and the working copy?

Comment: Have you looked add [.gitignore](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore)?

Comment: @Sjoerd I still want the file to be tracked, just not my local changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.py`. This will make `git` not notice any changes to the file **until you check out another branch or otherwise rebuild the index**. This is, unfortunately, the best solution if you need a long-term set of changes to a file which must be tracked in the repository (and not in `.gitignore`).

A better solution is to make the file not be tracked at all, and put it in your repository-specific `.git/info/excludes` or `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thanks. This answer led me to discover `--skip-worktree`, which seems to be a bit more resilient to resets and other repo operations. [This page](http://fallengamer.livejournal.com/93321.html) also mentions that it can be useful for tracked config files. I think that's probably the best solution out there right now.

Comment: @zildjohn01 That sounds great! I didn't know about that option.